# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I'm using Android Studio 1.3 and Java 1.8. recently when I'm building the app I got following error.

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

I removed some activities and rebuild it. it build properly. but when they are restored back got the error again.
I went through android developer site and do according to https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#mdex-gradle
but it didn't solve my issue. my App.java file is as below,

```
    public class App extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = App.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static Context mContext;

    private static App mInstance;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static synchronized App getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);

        Log.d("LF",req.toString());
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

and my gradle file looks like this

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.marpak.livefarmerpro"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 52
        versionName '1.9.1.5.23'
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile project(':holoColorPickermaster')
    compile project(':qRCodeReaderViewlib')
    compile project(':volley')
}
```

I went through all most all stack overflow answers on this and find no fix. looking forward a helpful answer. Thank you!

Comment: delete your app/build directory and  gradle build  your project

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. already tried, but does not fix the issue.

Comment: buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc3' is not stable and set compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Comment: okay set  buildToolsVersion 22

Comment: did it too. but same error.

Comment: Delete any newly installed plugin

Comment: In my 'External Libraries' folder, it contains all the Support Library components which are i'm not using and three android platforms. does it cause an issue like this.

Comment: If you external library project already contain support library then remove from your  project gradle file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but the libraries don't contain support library. I'm using volley, qrCodeReaderView and holoColorPickermaster libraries. neither of them contain support library.